# Could more badges have 'Go Get it' links please?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, profile-page

Some of the badges (like Archaeologist) could have some "Go get it" links in the User Profile in the "How do you earn this badge?" dialog.

Screenshot of what this is:

[image]

Is this possible? Is this planned?

Comment: Where would you go to? All the old questions on the site? All unanswered questions against all your favourite tags? Something else?

Comment: @RobertLongson Any LQ questions of 6 months or older. But I could be 'wrong' on that. I'm not asking for it to be done 'now' just enquiring if there were any general plans?

Comment: when you tag [feature-request] you're asking for it to be done now. If you just wanted to know what the plans are you would have tagged [support] or [discussion]

Comment: How is this question unclear? C'mon people.

Comment: @TimPost: What are 'go get it' links?

Comment: @PatrickHofman the button that shows up when you click (some) badges on the new profile. http://i.stack.imgur.com/AsgQD.png

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ: Okay. Clarified the question.

Comment: Added a screenshot as well.

Comment: With a FHC to boot!

Answer (score 8):

There are two things that we need in order to have 'Go get it' on a next badge. The first is, somewhere to link. The second is, well, the first, and some way to make it obvious what you're supposed to do there.

We also want the experience to be net positive for us and for the user. Saying "Here, quick, go find 100 things to edit" kinda scares me.

I'm open to suggestions on what we could link to (for any of them that don't have the button) - I'd really like for all but very few them to have it because it's such a convenient way *to be engaged* from a user's perspective.

Archeologist (it just so happens that you mentioned it as an example) might *not* be the best one to work on, but I'm open to ideas. If it makes sense, seems straight forward from a user's perspective *and it's a call to action that isn't too scary if it goes wrong* - we'll definitely consider it.